# EDM-Generated Database random data

Tags: c#, database, ado.net-entity-data-model

I have created a set of tables by executing SQL script generated by ADO.NET EDM. And I need these tables to have random data in them. My project are at start only, and database structure is recreated many times while designing, and I can't manually add random data each time.
 Is there any automated way to fill tables with random values(with article-like string data for field [article].[text], mail_name-like string data for field [user].[mail], etc.)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheWeeklySourceCode58GeneratingDatabaseTestDataWithAutoPocoAndEntityFrameworkCodeFirst.aspx) has the blog post about generating test data